# Javascript Templates - Deep nesting is it possible

Tags: javascript, asp.net, templates, nested, mustache

I am constructing a task app ( For fun) & i just sat down thinking about this problem. I will put the question on my mind in words here.

Model is extremely simple, it contains collection of `Project`. Each Project contains a `TaskList` these TaskList is **nestable** i.e for example a Task **Design FrontPage** can have **Design Header** as another `TaskList`. Each TaskList contain `Tasks`. How will a typical javascript template look like for this problem. I could not come with one that works this scenario. This problem is as same as **N level** nested Menu, how would you render it using templating library.

```
<div>
    {{#Projects}}
    <div>
        <b>{{ProjectName}}</b>
    </div>
    <ul>
        {{#TaskList}}
        <li>{{TaskListName}} {{CreatedBy}} The Problem Comes here - How do i Render a #TaskList
            here </li>
        {{/TaskList}}
    </ul>
    {{/Projects}}
</div>
```

btw if anyone has asp.net solution (Ideas for this let me hear them), N level deep nesting is the thing i am unable to overcome right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define your `TaskList` as a partial and include it recursively as [the documentation](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html) hints.

Templates:

```
<script type="text/template" id="projects">
    {{#Projects}}
    <div>
        Project: <b>{{ProjectName}}</b>
    </div>
    {{>taskList}}
    {{/Projects}}
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="task-list">
    {{#TaskList}}
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{TaskListName}} <em>{{CreatedBy}}</em> 
            {{>taskList}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    {{/TaskList}}
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var data = {
    Projects: [
        {
        ProjectName: "Project 1",
        TaskList: [{
            TaskListName: "Name 1",
            CreatedBy: "Person 1"},
        {
            TaskListName: "Name 2",
            CreatedBy: "Person 2",
            TaskList: [{
                TaskListName: "Sub Name",
                CreatedBy: "Same Person"},
            {
                TaskListName: "Sub Name 2",
                CreatedBy: "Person 1"},
            {
                TaskListName: "Sub Name 3",
                CreatedBy: "Person 3-2",
                TaskList: [{
                    TaskListName: "Sub Sub Name",
                    CreatedBy: "Person 3-3"}]}]}]},
    {
        ProjectName: "Project 2",
        TaskList: [{
            TaskListName: "Name 3",
            CreatedBy: "Person 3"},
        {
            TaskListName: "Name 4",
            CreatedBy: "Person 4"}]}]
},
    template = $('#projects').html(),
    partials = {
        taskList: $('#task-list').html()
    },
    html = Mustache.render(template, data, partials);

document.write(html);
```

Here's the jsFiddle to see it in action- http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/ND7xv/

Comment: and me thinking that partials were of less use. Awesome :) thank you for teaching me never to look-down on something

Comment: was looking for this from very long time..would have given double vote up...if i could...!!