# Asp Server Controls - Any controls with deep nesting other than menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, recursion, .net-2.0

Which are the server controls from asp.net 2.0 suite that i can use for deep nesting. This question is in relation with [other question i posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943771/javascript-templates-deep-nesting-is-it-possible/8959201) it became possible in Javascript Templating but could not on server side. Previously i used 2 repeaters to achieve 2 level nesting but now the requirement changed to N - level nesting hence i am stumbled as to how?

Comment: You can nest N Levels Deep with a repeater, I have seen 6-8 different Databound levels rendered reasonably well. Are you able to use third-party controls, Infragistics and Telerik controls support OLAP and N tier nesting.

Comment: @Lloyd No we are forbidden from using 3rd party controls else would have opted for Telerik's controls. Could you explain more on how you successfully nested the N Level repeater?

Comment: (Note this is not the same format as your previous question but as you said you were doing this for fun) You simply add the repeater in each RepeaterControls ItemTemplate or AlternatingItemTemplate and bind it to a DataSource during the OnItemDataBound  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220715/creating-a-nested-repeater-control-dynamically/1220836#1220836

Comment: @Lloyd sorry i wasn't clear. The implementation in javascript was for fun. The one with asp.net is currently what i seek through this question.

Comment: You can nest any DataBound TemplateControl and bind the Data to it during the OnItemDataBound event, if the Data you wish to bind is in the root Item you access from the DataItem property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which are the server controls from asp.net 2.0 suite that i can use
>   for deep nesting.

The controls that support binding to a hierarchical data source are the `<asp:Menu>` and `<asp:TreeView>` controls. Both controls inherit from the [`HierarchicalDataBoundControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hierarchicaldataboundcontrol.aspx) class.

If you need to support nesting and can't use a 3rd party control, then you will have to implement your own `HierarchicalDataBoundControl`.